# PHPMyAdmin The mbstring PHP extension was not found

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, centos7

PhpMyAdmin is reporting that `mbstring` isn't installed. I am using PHP 7.1 on Centos 7.

First i ran: `yum search mbstring` and found the package for php 7.1 is: `php71-php-mbstring.x86_64`

I then ran: `yum install yum install php71-php-mbstring.x86_64`

Everything seems to have installed fine but phpmyadmin is still saying mbstring isn't available and `phpinfo()` also shows it's not enabled.

Comment: May be missed restarting server? If you already done, then also check whether `mbstring` installed for base version of PHP(mostly 5).

Comment: I have restarted apache after the install

Comment: I think you have two or more installed phps so you need to check which one is running on your project and phpmyadmin. Also you can configure them which one runs for specific virtualservers.